# MapGet execution sequence in pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-6.0, minimal-apis

I have 2 pieces of code

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers["token"] != "my_token")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return;
    }

    await next();
});

app.Run();
```

and

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
    
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers["token"] != "my_token")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        return;
    }

    await next();
});

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

Difference is only location of `app.MapGet()` 
For the both code `app.Use()` is executed firstly, then `app.MapGet()`. 
What is a reason of this? Why isn't pipeline always executed based on the sequence of the middlewares?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [Routing in ASP.NET Core, Routing basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#routing-basics):

> Apps typically don't need to call `UseRouting` or `UseEndpoints`. WebApplicationBuilder configures a middleware pipeline that wraps middleware added in `Program.cs` with `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints`. However, apps can change the order in which `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` run by calling these methods explicitly. For example, the following code makes an explicit call to `UseRouting`:
>
> ```
> app.Use(async (context, next) =>
> {
>     // ...
>     await next(context);
> });
>
> app.UseRouting();
>
> app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If the preceding example didn't include a call to UseRouting, the custom middleware would run after the route matching middleware.

So the answer is because `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` by default will order the request pipeline such that endpoints always run last, unless you explicitly say you want to change that order.